# Wamp or php ñ error?

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, wampserver

In my Server Ive installed wamp 2.0i  and test my program. I am fetching last name from my table with ñ character  and tried  printing it  and here is the result: PARIÃ‘AS  which should be Pariñas

Ive tried running in on my another computer which has wamp 2.4  and its perfectly working.

So I uninstalled Wamp 2.0i in my server and installed wamp 2.4 and run the program yet it produces same result  PARIÃ‘AS.

I have  also JasperReports that create PDF from my query and the Result  from jasperServer   is Ok but when I connect to Php   the Pariñas turn into  Paricas. While in the another computer  its perfectly working and I cant figure it why?.

How  will I configure  My Wamp server to fix this error

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to a charset problem on your local pc, check this if you are using `chrome` https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95290?hl=en

otherwise try to search charset issues related to your browser over the web

edit: you can try to add this `<meta charset="UTF-8">` to your `<head>` tag and force the browser to use that kind of charset

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I remote access  the server in another computer the result is still the same. the second computer with wampserver 2.4  when access with another computer it perfectly fine

Comment: Did you try to add the `meta` tag inside your `<head>`?

Comment: its works , but how about my pdf  ?  it still turn to c

Comment: bro why  do I have to put meta  when  if I  run the program in another wamp in a diff computer  I dont have to? Just asking?

Comment: It's always a charset trick, you are trying to use chars that are not in the classic "set" of available charset, check the documentation from `JasperReports` (which i don't really know) and see if you can find something about the charset and how to change it

Comment: why do I have to put meta when if I run the program in another wamp in a diff computer I dont have to? Just asking?

Comment: Because the charset are something that should be installed on you computer (like fonts), maybe he had this kind of charset installed (maybe from a videogame or something else) and he doesn't have this kind of problems, i'm just guessing, i don't know how this actually works